# RegionCentroid giving different result on Polygon and ConvexHullMesh

Tags: regions, geometry, polygons, computational-geometry

I have the following 5 vertices:

```
vertices = 
{{-2.503485975950981768, -2.006172988860733142, 0.0361225958077370235}, 
{-1.665226663575889887,-1.93970052442889318, -0.3787121503721547766},
{-1.009480767611662833, -1.940989163656756, -0.3967434772896430428},
{-1.051677946279833797, -1.96320019333881679,-0.2673614821787158591}, 
{-2.25143108392933744, -2.086863843031371957,0.4904291491488624866}}
```

which are in the same plane:

```
Polygon[vertices] // RegionQ

(* True *)
```

I would like to calculate the centroid of the region enclosed by these vertices. For that, I can use `RegionCentroid[Polygon[vertices]]`.

However, I have other set of vertices which are not coplanar, so I prefer to use `RegionCentroid[ConvexHullMesh[vertices]]` instead, since it works also for 3-dimensional regions (see this [answers](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1593569)). The problem is that the result provided by both methods does not agree:

```
RegionCentroid[Polygon[vertices]]
RegionCentroid[ConvexHullMesh[vertices]]

(*
{-1.827420101, -1.999040579, -0.03113005572}
{-1.677685972, -1.988216531, -0.09919325584}
*)
```

Shouldn't `ConvexHullMesh` provide the same result as `Polygon` for a 2-dimensional region?

Comment: Cannot reproduce it in version 13.0.0 on Windows 10: `RegionCentroid[ConvexHullMesh[vertices]]` returns the input and an error message.

Comment: `ConvexHullMesh` does not handle degenerate sets (e.g. 3D-points  on the 2D-plane in  three dimensions).

Comment: `RegionCentroid[ConvexHullMesh[vertices]]` results in the error `RegionCentroid::reg ... is not a correctly specified region` on v12.2.0 Win7-x64.